# Open link from <a href> with HtmlUnit Java

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I have an html file that has this part:

```
<td> <a href="/romarin/detail.do?ID=0"> NAME </a> </td>
```

How can I open this link on `href` with HtmlUnit?

My code:

```
 final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11);
 final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("file:\\" + newrfile);
 final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submit");
 final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
 System.out.println(page2.asText());
 final HtmlForm form2 = page2.getFormByName("SearchForm");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [getAnchorByHref](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#getAnchorByHref(java.lang.String)):

```
HtmlAnchor htmlAnchor = page2.getAnchorByHref("/romarin/detail.do?ID=0");
```

Then you can click:

```
HtmlPage page3 = anchor.click();
```

Then you can save the page as a file:

```
page3.saveAs(some_file);
```

Or

```
System.out.println(page3.asXml());
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try.. Thanks

Comment: After I write that getAnchorByHref, can I save the html page that opened? How to save that page to the html file?

Comment: okay wait till tomorrow, because i still run this program for about 120000 data, so after i finish all, and there's no problem, i can accept it so everyone will get the best answer of yours... :)

Comment: Still have problem there. com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[a] attributeName=[href] attributeValue=[/romarin/detail.do?ID=0]
 at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.getOneHtmlElementByAttribute(HtmlElement.java:955)
 at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getAnchorByHref(HtmlPage.java:601)

Comment: Use `System.out.println(page3.asXml());` to see what HtmlUnit sees. Please update your question with the result.

Comment: actually i just got the answer by your answer, the problem is on the missing javascript. Thank you!!

Comment: hi, can i ask you more question, actually i already enter to the page 3 (destination page), but that page can't be opened because there is missing java. And the problem is I cant get page3's html file. Do you know how to get the html file? at least i can get the html code in my console. Thank you

Comment: Please create a new question. What is meant by 'missing java'? Also, if you can provide the complete test case (with URL), so others can reproduce your issue.

Comment: i want to create a new one, but i have to wait about 2 or 3 days here. or maybe can i have your email? so i can message you privately?